# Using multiple tables in one android application

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator, spinner

My application needs to use multiple tables under the same database. I am developing one global adapter and individual adapter for each tables to implement CRUD. Please see the database Adapter as below:

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public abstract class BahiKhataDbAdapter {

  protected static final String TAG = "BahiKhataDbAdapter";
      protected DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
      protected SQLiteDatabase mDb;

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bahikhatadata.db";

  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  protected static final String TABLE_EXPENSE_TYPE =
        "create table expensetype (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "expense_type text not null);";

  protected static final String TABLE_INCOME_TYPE =
        "create table incometype (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "income_type text not null);";

  protected static final String TABLE_GROUP =
        "create table group (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "group_name text not null);";

  protected static final String TABLE_EXPENSE =
        "create table expensetype (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "expense_amt real not null, note text, expense_type text not null, group   
      text not null, expense_date text not null);";


  protected static final String TABLE_INCOME =
        "create table expensetype (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "income_amt real not null, note text, income_type text not null, group 
              text not null, income_date text not null);";

      protected final Context mCtx;

  protected static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  DatabaseHelper (Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  } 


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(TABLE_EXPENSE_TYPE);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_INCOME_TYPE);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_GROUP);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_EXPENSE);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_INCOME);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS expensetype");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS incometype");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS group");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS expense");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS income");       
    onCreate(db);
}
   }

public BahiKhataDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
   }

public BahiKhataDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
   }
  }
```

and adapter for expensetype is as below:

```
     import android.content.ContentValues;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.database.Cursor;
     import android.database.DatabaseUtils;

     public class ExpenseTypeDbAdapter extends BahiKhataDbAdapter {

// Database fields
        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_NAME = "expense_type";
        private static final String DB_TABLE = "expensetype";

public ExpenseTypeDbAdapter(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
}


/**
 * Create a new business If the business is successfully created return the new
 * rowId for that note, otherwise return a -1 to indicate failure.
 */
public long createExpenseType(String name) {
    //ContentValues values = createContentValues(name);

    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    return mDb.insert(DB_TABLE, null, args);
}

/*private ContentValues createContentValues(String expense_type) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, expense_type);         
    return values;
}*/

/**
 * Deletes expensetype record
 */
public boolean deleteExpenseType(String expense_type) {
    return mDb.delete(DB_TABLE, "KEY_NAME=?", new String[] {expense_type}) > 0;
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor over the list of all todo in the database
 * 
 * @return Cursor over all notes
 */
public Cursor fetchAllExpenseType() {
    return mDb.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public long count() {
       return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDb, DB_TABLE);
  }

   }
```

and using the ExpenseTypeDbAdapter in one of my activity as below: (in this activity I am using the Spinner to populate the data of expensetype table. Please see the code as below:

```
   import android.app.Activity;
  //import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
   import android.widget.Spinner;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class ExpenseTypeList extends Activity  implements OnClickListener ,    
       OnItemSelectedListener{

/** Properties **/
  protected Spinner expenseSpinner;
  protected Button expenseDone;
  protected Button addNewExpenseType;
  protected ExpenseTypeDbAdapter dbHelper;
  protected String expenseType;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.expense);

    dbHelper = new ExpenseTypeDbAdapter(this);

    //configure the widgets
    addNewExpenseType = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_new_expense_type);
    expenseDone       = (Button) findViewById(R.id.expense_done);

    // Setup ClickListeners
    addNewExpenseType.setOnClickListener(this);
    expenseDone.setOnClickListener(this);

    // initialize the database
    dbHelper.open();

    expenseSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.expense_spinner);

    //populated the spinner from the ExpenseData db

    if(dbHelper.count() == 0) {
          dbHelper.createExpenseType("Jan");
          dbHelper.createExpenseType("Feb");
          dbHelper.createExpenseType("Mar");
          dbHelper.createExpenseType("Apr");

        }

    getSpinnerData();
    expenseSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

  }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(spinner == expenseSpinner) {
              // get the expense type
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) spinner.getSelectedItem();
            expenseType   = cursor.getString(1);
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v == expenseDone) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, expenseType + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Uri data = Uri.parse(expenseType);
            Intent result = new Intent(null, data);
            result.putExtra("EXPENSE_TYPE", expenseType);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
            finish();

        }
        if(v == addNewExpenseType){
            Toast.makeText(this, expenseType + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddExpenseType.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           }
    }

    public void getSpinnerData(){

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllExpenseType();

        String[] from = new String[] {ExpenseTypeDbAdapter.KEY_NAME}; //use class name directly

        int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter expenseCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
          this,
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
          cursor,
          from,
          to
        );

        expenseSpinner.setAdapter(expenseCursorAdapter);
        expenseCursorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (dbHelper != null) {
            dbHelper.close();
        }
    }
      }
```

ExpenseTypeList is not working; it is giving error of SQLite = 1; syntax error in create of group table. I tired to run after commenting the "create group" syntax and uninstalled the application from Android emulator; but still getting the error.

Could somebody help me out to run this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating several instances of SQLiteOpenHelper is not usually a wise choice since they're more or less expecting to be exclusive with the .db file.

Answer (score 1):

"group" is a keyword, try renaming your table.
TABLE_EXPENSE_TYPE and TABLE_EXPENSE have the same table name.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone; your review comments helped me out to fix it.